# Timeouts on a website - tech support says the fault must be local to me

Tags: domain-name-system, routing, nameserver, isp

I try and access a webpage, http://billing.webhosting.uk.com, and almost always get timeouts. I contacted their tech support and they said no one else has reported issues, and that the issue must be local to me.

I wonder if anyone else experiences timeouts trying to access this page. (I am browsing from Belfast, Northern Ireland.)

What would be a sequence for testing whether the problem is my local network, my ISP, or things like DNS services?

Comment: Sign up for a Pingdom.com account, which will hit the page every few minutes and record a) whether it worked and b) how long it took.

Comment: Just signed up, will see what the results look like.

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of monitoring services and tools you can use to check the accessibility of a website from locations spread all over the world, and I guess I may as well give credit to the two free ones I like.  (As with most places offering these quick, free tools, they also have more in depth tools and monitoring services for sale.)

[Uptrends](http://www.uptrends.com/aspx/free-website-server-network-monitoring-tool.aspx)

[Zoho's Site24x7](http://www.site24x7.com/check-website-availability.html)

Run those against the website periodically and see if it really is just you/your ISP, or if tech support is saying whatever they have to in order to get you off the phone.

Answer (score 1):

Checking from the States: it looks like it's only down for you per the indispensable [DownForEveryoneOrJustMe? site](http://www.downforeveryoneorjustme.com/http://billing.webhosting.uk.com/).

Comment: I should have explained better - for me the index page gives a 200 fairly quickly but dependent files like CSS and Javascript take forever and mostly ABORT. Useful link though!

Comment: It's a good resource, but probably won't help in this case - the check it does is generally too simple to be useful for troubleshooting, unless of course, you use it to find out that your webiste is down for everyone.

Answer (score 1):

Had this happen to a customer. They swore up and down that there is no problem on their side. In the end, it was the ISPs DSL modem that was the problem . They never were able to say exactly what, but when it was replaced, the problem went away.

Comment: Well that too is a possibility at this stage :)